# How can I convert a string into an integer in RUBY?

Tags: ruby, string, type-conversion, integer

I am learning RUBY and I do not know how can we convert string to integer. For example odd or even number of letters, etc.

Comment: '12'.to_i will convert into 12

Comment: However, the question implies you want to know about the length of the string? `'Ruby'.length` will be 4.

Comment: Can you give a more explicit example? It’s unclear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert string to integer: `my_str.to_i`, for example

```
"foo".to_i       # 0
"132".to_i       # 132
"132.4".to_i     # 132
"foo132".to_i    # 0
"132foo".to_i    # 132
```

To find if a string has an odd or even number of characters: `my_str.length.odd?` or `my_str.length.even?`, for example:

```
"foo".length.odd?    # true
"132".length.odd?    # true
"foo".length.even?   # false
"132".length.even?   # false
```

**SEE ALSO:**

[`to_i`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-to_i)

Answer (score 4):

To convert a string to an integer, use `#to_i`

```
'12'.to_i
=> 12
```

Once it's an integer, you can test for odd or even...

```
'12'.to_i.odd?
=> false
'12'.to_i.even?
=> true
```

For length (number of digits) for an integer, you can count the digits...

```
'12'.to_i.abs.digits.count
=> 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The question does state integer, but some strings can represent floats or rationals or even hexidecimals

```
'2'.to_i => 2 # Fixnum
'2.01'.to_f => 2.01 # Float
'2'.to_r => (2/1) # Rational
'2'.to_c => (2+0i) # Complex
```

`to_i` assumes a 10-base representation, but Ruby allows you to change that

```
'2'.to_i(base=2) => 0 # Fixnum
```

`to_i` can also handle hexadecimal 'numbers'

```
`b`.to_i(base=16) => 11 # Fixnum
```

`to_i` converts all numeric characters from the beginning of a string until the iterable encounters a character that cannot be coerced to an integer type.

```
'12a'.to_i => 12 # Fixnum
```